# How can I get the fixed version of deja-dup installed?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Given this:
[Duplicity error having to do with python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901319/duplicity-error-having-to-do-with-python)

...and version 16.04 LTS

How can I get the updated version installed? Without a systems backup, we are in a non-compliant state and will be forced to abandon the Ubuntu platform if we cannot fix it. The bugs in question seem to be fixed. What's the hold-up? LTS is the "stability" version, right??

Comment: "Without a systems backup, we are in a non-compliant state" sorry but there are a lot better ways to create a backup if you need to comply to business rules. A manual backup of /home/ for instance.

Comment: What do you propose for clerks & marketing managers who work for companies that have Microsoft-only IT departments? I suppose they should all learn to do without a GUI also? Scripting skills shouldn't be necessary for the basic use of a modern computer system & the worse part is that the fix is already completed & likely deployed on some other version.  LTS is the version that needs it though. It's the one the grandparents & marketing managers are using.

Comment: No. Just a simple rightclick in nautilus and "add to archive". And copy that archive to google drive or something similar.

Comment: ...and 8 Gigs of files later without a differential backup * 100+ employees... Google is not permitted for corporate use, regardless. Frankly, I agree with that position. Clouds exist because someone wants access they should not have to your data or because they want an option for vendor lock-in for the foolish. For my personal use, I use SSH and Unison with a port forward from my router and DDNS. IMHO, this is plenty more secure than a cloud that has "we are going to spy on you and abuse your private information" right in the license and/or terms of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo apt-get install sbackup

This app is nearly the same as deja-dup. One minor flaw is that it is supposed to display status in the notification area but doesn't. I've found some other options, if this one doesn't work out but so far it's working fine.

-OK one additional caveat. It doesn't handle spaces. If you have spaces in the path for your backup drive, you will have to rename the drive using `gparted`. This doesn't mean you have to erase the drive.